# Dynamic data graph on Blogger - what to use?

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have a data of say 100 rows. What kind of technology can I use on Blogger.com to output a dynamic bar chart where the number of records shown is user-controlled via a button or slider? For example: Show top 10, top 20, etc.

My main problem is that I am not sure of
1. How to host the data externally 
2. How to output it dynamically on web

Keep in mind that my PHP and JavaScript are weak, so I prefer other options if possible. Also, this is on google's Blogger platform, and I do not have any of my own web hosting

Answer (score 1):

Blogger doesn't work as a dynamic site. You can do this in only dynamic sites. There are two options are available to show your pages on blogger.

1. Try to use jQuery script to load the pages.
2. Manually create 100 pages of data in blogger. Since it takes few days to complete all the pages and then link the all the pages in main page.

Comment: so if i want to use a dynamic site... do i have to have my own hosting? or are there free hosted options out there?

Comment: Better you can buy hosting from any providers. If you using free hosting option from free provides then they might show ads to your website and they give minimum of bandwidth data.. hope you can understand.